# django-paypal payment complete but signal failed

Tags: django, django-signals, django-paypal

I am using [django-paypal](https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal) for django 1.7 project. Now I am testing on a paypal sandbox.

Whenever I made a payment, the process at paypal was successful. I can see the buyer account amount deducted, and in the business account accept the money.

Basically, when user make a successful payment , some objects will be updated. But, during my test payment, the object was not updated, seem like the payment signal was not called at all.

Another weird thing is, when I check on the ipn at the admin, i see there were two records for single transaction. One is flagged but no error message and another one is not flagged but give an error message 'Duplicate txn_id xxxxx'. Both records shows that the payment status was 'Completed'.

I really don't know what is going wrong, the documentation doesn't shows how to debug the problem.

On the bottom of the models.py
    from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import payment_was_successful

```
def Paypal_comfirm(sender, **kwargs):
    ipn_obj = sender
    if ipn_obj.payment_status == "Completed":

        orderid = ipn_obj.invoice
        theorder = get_object_or_404(Order, pk=orderid)
        theorder.status = 'complete'
        theorder.txn_id = ipn_obj.txn_id
        theorder.date_pay = timezone.now()
        theorder.save()

payment_was_successful.connect(Paypal_comfirm)
```

I noticed that you can also use `payment_was_flagged` signal, but I don't know what to do with it.

Has anyone know how to debug this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it's my signal function that got problems. If your set debug = False (which normally you will do when deployed on a live server) on the settings.py, then you will not get the error logs (on heroku). All I can see is a bad 500 error request, this is very hard to tell what are the problem.

Just in case for who want have the similar problem, you can add the [ADMINS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/) to the settings.py.

So whenever there is error in your site, you will get the error sending to your email. 
Of course , you'll need to add your email details in the settings.py as well.